# Turn by turn navigation

Tags: google-maps, gps, ionic-framework

Is there a plugin library I can use in Ionic that will get me the basic functionality of turn by turn navigation?  What is the technical name for this feature?

Answer (score 1):

There a plugin for that:
[uk.co.workingedge.phonegap.plugin.launchnavigator](https://github.com/dpa99c/phonegap-launch-navigator#using-the-cli)

You would need an `GOOGLE_MAP_API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID` when you install the plugin (read documentation) that you can get from the `google.cloud` console, under credentials, as well as the library **@ionic-native/launch-navigator**.

If you run into some error trying to instantiate the launchNavigator object, just regress the version to version 4 when you npm install the library ( `npm install @ionic-native/launch-navigator@4` )

Answer (score 0):

I think the quickest way is to launch the Google Maps by intent.

Otherwise, you would have to do it yourself by using the [Google Maps Javascript API Directions Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions), the result contains lat/lngs of the path, as well as turn by turn directions' instruction.